# How to get Tesseract confidence levels in python or command window?

Tags: python, tesseract

How can we get the confidence levels after OCR of an image using tesseract 3.05 in windows? I am calling tesseract from python using subprocess commands:

`retcode = subprocess.call("tesseract -l eng myImage.png txt -psm 6" , stdin=None, stdout=False, stderr=None, shell=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the wrapper that you need:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserocr/2.0.0 . Also there are tons of python wrapper out there, but this library is the closest wrapper that nearly cover all of C++ API.

Example:

```
from PIL import Image
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI

image = Image.open('/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif')
with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    api.SetImage(image)
    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
    print 'Found {} textline image components.'.format(len(boxes))
    for i, (im, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
        # im is a PIL image object
        # box is a dict with x, y, w and h keys
        api.SetRectangle(box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h'])
        ocrResult = api.GetUTF8Text()
        conf = api.MeanTextConf()
        print (u"Box[{0}]: x={x}, y={y}, w={w}, h={h}, "
               "confidence: {1}, text: {2}").format(i, conf, ocrResult, **box)
```

Comment: It might be good to make it clear that the code there is an example from the page on PyPI.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I am having problems with installing tesserocr on windows machine. It requires CPP build tools 2014 which seems hard to find. I have user pytesser package and it works for tesseract-ocr, but as you mentioned doesnt give enough flexibility. tesseract-ocr 4.0 version is not giving conf in tsv file. I am not sure why.

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage  -> Based on this site, maybe it is only available for 3.05 (devBranch).  If you use Pytesseract library, directly adding "tsv" option to  process inside "def process_request" function would be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Stef's answer, here is a sample command to check the confidence value in 'output.tsv' file.

*tesseract Ancestry1.jpg output --oem 1 -l eng tsv*

Here, 'Ancestry1.jpg' is the image file to be input to tesseract.
oem 1 is for using the LSTM in 4.0.
The confidence is stored in 'output.tsv' file

The link to the official Tesseract webpage for confidence levels: [Tesseract Wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#tsv-output-currently-available-in-305-dev-in-master-branch-on-github)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [tsv output](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Command-Line-Usage.md#tsv-output-currently-available-in-305-dev-in-master-branch-on-github):

```
tesseract testing/eurotext.png testing/eurotext-eng -l eng tsv
```

The confidence level is in the last but one column.

Comment: I am using tesseract 4.0 version and when outputting tsv, the conf column is empty. Should I use another version of tesseract-ocr?

Comment: You should replace 'txt' with 'tsv' and you will get the conf column